# Create React App Blank Page when including on existing site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using XAMPP locally to host an exisiting CMS and I want to include my react app within the CMS by using an include (this works fine for including static HTML and other PHP pages). The CMS admin page it'll be included on will look like this: http://localhost/website/administrator/

I need to place my create-react-app in a folder like this though so that the built in CMS script will include it: `website\subfolder1\subfolder2\subfolder3\subfolder4\default`

Currently I'm getting a blank page where I've tried to include my app. If I remove the embedded  I can see the markup is being output, as in an empty div with the root class name.

I've tried setting a "homepage" property in my package.json and various combinations such as '.', and also edited the manifest site_start without luck, i can't seem to get it to render. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: open the console, if it's a react problem, probably it will have some error...

Comment: @Vencovsky Thanks for the reply but there are no errors in the console. I believe it to be some kind of webpack configuration error. Just for clarify I can also do a no build app, just including react via a cdn in a html document, and it works fine so there's no issue with the CMS and including react either. Seems to point to a problem with the site_start setting or "homepage" setting, or a mixture of both.

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of the create-react-app then ejecting the create-react-app and changing where the bundle is built to your path in the webpack config?

Comment: Thanks @RobertAnderson it sounds like something I would need to do to get this working. Are you able to clarify a little more how I would go about doing that? Currently I've tried building the app and just renaming the folder to the 'default' one the CMS is looking for. I've also tried manually editing the index.html paths to the js and css files to ensure they're loaded in correctly.

Comment: @Rallen yeah it is :)

Comment: @alienbuild are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @Rallen No I'm currently just building the default create-react-app to ensure I can include it correctly and nothing else is conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps that you could try to get the bundles building correctly, as you will need to override the default behaviour of create-react-app by ejecting.

1. Make a backup copy of your create-react-app
2. Eject, so that you will now be able to configure webpack
   n

```js
npm run eject
```

3. Go to webpack config, see the scripts section
4. You can change the build scripts as such as start and build
5. The issue seems to be where the js and css files are built to. You can change where they are output in webpack by editing the config.

See link: https://webpack.js.org/configuration

You could try changing the path for the output section to where your cms html is trying to find the bundle.

Comment: Thank you. I shall give it a go and I'm sure the answer lies somewhere in here.